# How to call activity from another fragment.?

Tags: android, fragment

I already know how to make a fragment in Android. I want to open another activity in the same fragment on a button click event. The button is inside a fragment class.

How do I do that?

Comment: or you can also use [result-receiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html)

Answer (score 2):

There are two possibilities depending on what you need:

- [Fragment Receive Result](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/FragmentReceiveResult.html) that demonstrates starting a new Activity from a Fragment, and receiving a result back from it.
- [setTargetFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setTargetFragment%28android.app.Fragment,%20int%29) may be used, for example, if this fragment is being started by another, and when done wants to give a result back to the first. An example is available [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentRetainInstanceSupport.html)

Answer (score 0):

All Fragment-to-Fragment communication is done through the associated Activity. Two Fragments should never communicate directly.

Here are some tutorials with example

- http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-using-fragments/
- http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

**EDIT: April 2013**

I like @AlexLockwood's comment.

In the case that one fragment starts another fragment, it's fine to just use `setTargetFragment(Fragment, int)` and communicate with it directly by calling `getTargetFragment()`. Communicating with Fragments through the activity is usually a good idea because it keeps your fragments loosely coupled from one another.

Comment: This is usually true, but in the case that one fragment starts another fragment, it's fine to just use `setTargetFragment(Fragment, int)` and communicate with it directly by calling `getTargetFragment()`. Communicating with Fragments through the activity is usually a good idea because it keeps your fragments loosely coupled from one another.